# Как добавить данные из 2 массивов в строку dataGridView?

Tags: c#

подсобите знаниями не понимаю в чем суть и почему не выходит сделать то чего хочу.

Есть 2 массива List назовем образно массив1 массив2
В 1-м всегда одинаковое количество столбцов во 2-м динамично

Хочу вывести их в строку dataGridView1
делаю так
`this.dataGridView1.Rows.Add(массив1,массив2);`
ничего не получается вернее вместо данных массива вижу System.String[] в 1 и втором столбце.
В то-же время по отдельности они отлично выводятся
`this.dataGridView1.Rows.Add(массив1);`
Более того что бы я не добавил к массиву переменную или просто строку
`this.dataGridView1.Rows.Add("тестовая запись",массив1);`
массив перестает выводится

Задача вывести в строку грида несколько переменных и массив по моим представлениям это должно выглядеть так
`this.dataGridView1.Rows.Add(переменная1,переменная2,переменная3,массив1);`
на практике не работает.
Как это делается правильно?

Comment: `dataGridView.DataSource = /* источник данных */;` - правильно делается так.

Comment: Вам необходимо преобразовать оба листа в один, где для первого листа также будут присутствовать столбцы из второго листа. Далее, как уже Вам подсказал Alexander Petrov, использовать [DataSource](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-RU/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datagridview.datasource).

Answer (score 0):

> Есть 2 массива List назовем образно массив1 массив2

Нет. Давайте будем точны в определениях. [List](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1?view=net-5.0) - это **не** [массив](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/arrays/)!
Судя по дальнейшему описанию, у вас именно массивы, а не списки. Обозначим их `array1`, `array2`.

Метод `Add` имеет [перегрузку](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datagridviewrowcollection.add?view=net-5.0#System_Windows_Forms_DataGridViewRowCollection_Add_System_Object___), которая принимает `params object[] values`.
Когда вы пишете `Add(array1)`, то каждый *элемент* массива воспринимается как отдельный объект. И колонках грида оказываются *элементы* массива.
Когда вы пишете `Add(array1, array2)`, то каждый *массив* воспринимается как отдельный объект. И в колонках оказываются *массивы* (у них вызывается метод `ToString()`).

Что предпринять? Создать новый массив и скопировать данные в него.

```
var result = new string[array1.Length + array2.Length];
array1.CopyTo(result, 0);
array2.CopyTo(result, array1.Length);

dataGridView.Rows.Add(result); // теперь это работает
```

---

> Как это делается правильно?

Правильно - использовать [привязку данных](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/winforms/windows-forms-data-binding?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8).
Использовать свойство [DataSource](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datagridview.datasource?view=net-5.0)
Но это отдельная тема. Задайте *новый* вопрос, в случае необходимости.